# orderBy most occurring but return all rows

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

What I'm basically trying to do is order my collection based on most occurring `item_id` within the results.

For example; I've got a table with the following data:

```
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| id | item_id | column2 | column3 | column4 |
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| 1  | 12      | Hi      | DataHere| MoreData|
| 2  | 12      | Hi      | DataHere| MoreData|
| 3  | 14      | Hi      | DataHere| MoreData|
| 4  | 13      | Hi      | DataHere| MoreData|
| 5  | 12      | Hi      | DataHere| MoreData|
| 6  | 21      | Hi      | DataHere| MoreData|
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

How I'd be accessing the initial table would be with a simple `MyData::get()` model & accessor.

I've tried doing the following but can only get the `item_id` & `count` to return, I need all columns to be returned, just ordered by the most frequent `item_id`'s

```
MyData::select(\DB::raw('item_id'), \DB::raw('count(*) as count'))->having('item_id', '>', '0')->groupBy('item_id')->orderBy('count', 'desc')->get();
```

My expected result would be:

```
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| id | item_id | column2 | column3 | column4 |
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| 1  | 12      | Hi      | DataHere| MoreData|
| 2  | 12      | Hi      | DataHere| MoreData|
| 5  | 12      | Hi      | DataHere| MoreData|
| 6  | 21      | Hi      | DataHere| MoreData|
| 3  | 14      | Hi      | DataHere| MoreData|
| 4  | 13      | Hi      | DataHere| MoreData|
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$table = app(MyData::class)->getTable();
MyData::selectRaw("*, (select count(*) from $table t where t.item_id = $table.item_id) as count")
    ->orderBy('count', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```

You can replace the first line and `$table` with the actual table name. And `*` with whichever fields you actually want to select.

In fact, if you don't need the `count` in the select, you could just do:

```
$table = app(MyData::class)->getTable();
MyData::orderByRaw("(select count(*) from $table t where t.item_id = $table.item_id) DESC")
    ->get();
```

Answer (score -3):

You can query inside DB.raw such as: `DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT p.name, part.*  FROM programs p, parts part  WHERE p.id = part.id"));`